# why alert is not fire using angular js in controller

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am trying to make a login page. I have one controller on my login page. On button click I am showing an alert. But it is not displaying. I created a  module of controller that why I am not able to create plunker or fiddle. I will share my small code in which I write a controller.

[Here is my code](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mq2vdmxmx5qbfdd/testapp.zip?dl=0)

**LoginCtrl.js**

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    function ctrl($scope, $state) {

        $scope.login = function () {
           alert("--")
        };

    }

    ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];
    return ctrl;

});
```

**controller.js**

```
/*global define, require */

define(function (require) {

    'use strict';

    var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers', []);

    controllers.controller('LoginCtrl', require('controllers/LoginCtrl'));

    return controllers;

});
```

Comment: There isn't enough code here in the question to know what's wrong, and most people don't download random code from dropbox or similar.  I'm not sure what having your code in a module has to do with not being able to provide a plunker.

Comment: actually there is no online editor which make directory ..issue when I am creating directory

Comment: is `LoginCntrl.js` really the name of your file or is that a typo? because your require statement has a different spelling.

Comment: @Claies by mistake i write this please download code then you understand ..better .it is not virus .it is small code and run index.html

Comment: "download this, it's not a virus".... really, not happening.  Read http://stackoverflow/help/mcve

Comment: beside the fact that since that appears to be in your personal dropbox, once the question is answered, what's to stop you from removing the code, rendering the question (and potential answers) useless to others in the future?

Comment: ok ...have you check my code ?

Comment: Not going to happen.  Format your question appropriately if you are interested at all in an answer.

Comment: Here, use this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview. Format it to fit your code.

Comment: @shmck in that we cannot  create directory mean folder .I need o create folder .Inside that I need to create js file

Comment: Another option is to post your code on Github. As you know, the Internet isn't a place where people trust downloads from anonymous names like `user944513`.

Comment: ok I will try ...my best

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your HTML file you have added the controller name to the parent element or the appropriate element.You need to give the same controller name in both your HTML file and also the js file.
Make sure your controller file is included in your index.html file.